# Produce Overlapping Triangles Using Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to produce a particular pattern using Python Turtle but I am having problems. I've created the first triangle but I am not sure how I go by adding the second one in it and coloring it.

What I need it to be: http://gyazo.com/5abdd3bc05a44945f1a74286e2ad43c6

What I currently have: http://gyazo.com/65357ea5d43a7dc49e89879a27e980b4

Code so far:

```
forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)
right(120)
done()
```

Comment: You need to add your code, not just your output

Comment: You can use the [`fill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.fill) and [`fillcolor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.fillcolor) commands

Comment: And you just have to reverse your turtle 180 degrees, move forward 100 and start drawing again.

Comment: @zehnpaard How do I go by doing that? Sorry trying to learn

Comment: Turning around 180 degrees is either `right(180)` or `left(180)`.  Since you did `right(120)` already before `done()`, you need to turn another `right(60)` to turn around a full 180 degrees, and then do `forward(100)`.  Turn left/right the correct amount of degrees (that's really for you to figure out) and repeat the code you already have to draw another triangle.

Comment: @zehnpaard Thanks for your help I've managed to get this so far:                                        http://gyazo.com/57b87d0481d65341fd8f38985a89b034, how do I make the turtle go into the first one as in the picture above?

Comment: You want to shift the 2nd triangle to the right by 100, so basically you want to move the turtle right by 100 (rotate it to point horizontally, `forward(100)` and rotate it again) *before* you start drawing the 2nd triangle.  You do the same again w/ the 3rd triangle as well.

Comment: @zehnpaard Thanks for helping me, but I'm still unsure, do you mind just doing this one for me? I'm a bit stuck on this part doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Might look something like this: http://ideone.com/5ebRb5

Comment: @zehnpaard Thank you so much! How am I able to colour it in now?

Comment: Surround the code that creates a particular triangle with `fill(True)`/`fill(False)` and the color specification using `fillcolor("blue")` etc, like so: http://ideone.com/mFYiov

Comment: @zehnpaard Thanks a lot for your help, just one last question. How am I able to fill the triangle in the middle? This is how it looks like: http://gyazo.com/74435697feadb01df048211be82cbdde

Comment: move your turtle to the right position, and draw a triangle where each side is 100, not 200.

Comment: @zehnpaard I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. Can you elaborate if that's ok? Thank you!!!!

Comment: Followup question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005371/turtle-make-triangle-different-color

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
import turtle
def draw_square(turtle, length):
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(90)

def Retat_square(turtle, length,nbr):
    for i in range(nbr):
        draw_square(turtle, length) 
        turtle.right(360/nbr)

def main():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("blue")
```

above is a method which will draw a square and below calling that method with turtle class

```
s = turtle.Turtle()
s.shape("turtle")
s.color("yellow")
s.speed()

Retat_square(s,100,30)
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: The OP's question was about filling two or three overlapping triangles with different colors.  This answer generates dozens of squares with no fill color whatsoever. Can you be more explicit how it bears on the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete solution based on *stamping* instead of *drawing* which can be the better way to go with some turtle problems:

```
import turtle
from operator import add

RED = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
GREEN = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
SUM = map(add, RED, GREEN)

TRIANGLE_SIZE = 200
BORDER_SIZE = 5

STAMP_UNIT = 20
SQRT_3 = 3 ** 0.5

turtle.shape("triangle")
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.right(30)  # realign triangle
turtle.fillcolor(RED)
turtle.shapesize(TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT, TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT, BORDER_SIZE)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.fillcolor(GREEN)
y_offset = TRIANGLE_SIZE * SQRT_3 / 4
turtle.goto(TRIANGLE_SIZE / 4, -y_offset)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.shapesize(TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT / 2, TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT / 2, BORDER_SIZE)
turtle.fillcolor(SUM)
turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 2 * y_offset / 3)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.exitonclick()
```

I'll discuss the color mixing in answer to [the followup question to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005371/turtle-make-triangle-different-color).

**OUTPUT**

[image]