# Turtle make triangle different color

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Hi guys I'm trying to replicate this image:

[image]

It's almost done I just have one issue, where the triangle is supposed to be yellow it isn't seeming to work.

Mine:

[image]

Code:

```
fill(True)
fillcolor('green')
width(3)
forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)

fill(False)


right(180)
forward(100)
right(60)
forward(100)
left(120)




fill(True)
fillcolor('red')
forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)
fill(False)
```

Any help would be appreciated. (I can't add yellow to the second part of the code)

Comment: What makes you think the image should be yellow from your code? You never set the color to yellow.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, `turtle` does not support transparency. The green triangle will overlay the red triangle and the area where they overlap will not "add" to yellow. You have to explicitly draw the yellow triangle. Try adding this to your code:

```
fill(True)
fillcolor('yellow')
left(120)
forward(100)
left(120)
forward(100)
left(120)
forward(100)
fill(False)
```

Also, it might be a good idea to define a function `def triangle(size, color)` to reduce the amount of repetition in your code, e.g. like this:

```
def triangle(size, color):
    fill(True)
    fillcolor(color)
    for _ in range(3):      
        forward(size)
        left(120)
    fill(False)
```

Then you just have to position the turtle and call that function to draw a triangle.

Comment: Worked partially, I ended up getting this. http://gyazo.com/a60af09529d33eb55a9ad8b3f6d50f3b

Comment: @Sarah Then you must have changed some of your other code in the mean time. When adding this just below the code in your question it will work.

Comment: As I said, you have to put that code _below_ your code. You put it right in the middle, between drawing the green and the red triangle. The yellow triangle is "on top", so you have to draw it _last_.

Answer (score 0):

Although turtle does not support transparency, we can still do some color mixing in Python rather than hardcode "yellow":

```
from operator import add

RED = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
GREEN = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
SUM = map(add, RED, GREEN)
```

This gives us the option of trying some other primary colors and seeing what their mix comes out to be.  For example:

```
import turtle
from operator import add

PRIMARY_1 = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # red
PRIMARY_2 = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)  # blue
SECONDARY_SUM = map(add, PRIMARY_1, PRIMARY_2)

TRIANGLE_SIZE = 200
BORDER_SIZE = 5

STAMP_UNIT = 20
SQRT_3 = 3 ** 0.5

turtle.shape("triangle")
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.right(30)  # realign triangle
turtle.fillcolor(PRIMARY_1)
turtle.shapesize(TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT, TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT, BORDER_SIZE)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.fillcolor(PRIMARY_2)
y_offset = TRIANGLE_SIZE * SQRT_3 / 4
turtle.goto(TRIANGLE_SIZE / 4, -y_offset)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.shapesize(TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT / 2, TRIANGLE_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT / 2, BORDER_SIZE)
turtle.fillcolor(SECONDARY_SUM)
turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 2 * y_offset / 3)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Clearly, this approach is overly simplistic and for true mixing the code will need to be more sophisticated.  But we don't have to give up completely by hardcoding colors due to lack of transparency.

**OUTPUT**

[image]